# download edited data table gives warning in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Here is an example shiny app that allows user to download editable table. User can click on the `csv` button on the upper left corner to download the table.

However, I found after I edit any cell in the table (by double click on any cell and modify contents), when I click on the `csv` button, enter file name and save, I got warning message like below:

```
dataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_3 - invalid json response. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Although I was still able to save the table as csv file, the warning message is very annoying.

This only happens after I add the argument `server=FALSE` in the `renderDT` function. The reason I need `server=FALSE` is without this, the app only download the first page of the folder (missing all the rest of data after saving).

Another problem is after I edit a cell, if I check/uncheck some columns, the editted cell goes back to its original value.

Does anyone know how to fix these issues?

Thanks a lot.

The example shiny app is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
    # UI
    ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                   checkboxGroupInput('datacols', 
                                      label='Select Columns:',
                                      choices= c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Specie'),
                                      selected = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Specie'),
                                      inline=TRUE )

                   ),

    # SERVER
    server = function(input, output) {



        df = reactiveValues()

        observe ({

            df$dat = iris %>% select(one_of(input$datacols))
        })
        # render DT
        output$tbl = renderDT(server=FALSE, {
                datatable(df$dat,
                editable = "cell",
                extensions = "Buttons",
                options = list(
                    dom = "Bfrtip", buttons = list("csv")))

        })


        observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
            cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
            df$dat  <- editData(df$dat,  input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], "tbl")
        })

    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using the proxy with `server = FALSE`. You should not. Do

```
observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
  cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
  df$dat <- editData(df$dat,  input[["tbl_cell_edit"]])
})
```

and not

```
observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
  cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
  df$dat <- editData(df$dat,  input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], "tbl")
})
```

If you want to download the whole table with `server = TRUE`, see [this discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267#issuecomment-502552589).

Comment: thanks a lot. That works.  I do not see the warning message after removing the `"tbl"` from the code.   Would you mind explain why that works ?

Comment: `"tbl"` is the proxy. To use only with `server = TRUE`.

Comment: Actually I found another issue from this app.  After I edit a cell, if I check/uncheck some columns, the edited cell goes back to its original value.  do you know how I can fix this?   Let's keep server=FALSE.   Really appreciate your help!  @Stéphane Laurent

Comment: I opened another question as an extension of this.  really appreciate it if you could take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194938/edited-cell-in-data-table-goes-back-to-its-original-value-after-check-uncheck-co  @Stéphane Laurent